# java weblogic.WLST script.sh giving name error : python

Tags: python, oracle, weblogic, nameerror, wlst

I have four WLST scripts `check_script1.py`, `check_script2.py`, `check_script3.py` and `check_sccript4.py`. I want to execute all these four in parallel. So I created a checkscript.sh file like this :
This runs scripts one after the other

```
#!/bin/sh
python check_script1.py 
python check_script2.py 
python check_script3.py 
python check_script4.py
```

java weblogic.WLST checkscript.sh
I got this error :

> Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):   File
>   "/scratch/scripts/sails/checkscript.sh", line 2, in ? NameError:
>   python

When i executed this(parallel) :

```
#!/bin/sh
python check_script1.py &
python check_script2.py &
python check_script3.py &
python check_script4.py &
java weblogic.WLST checkscript.sh
```

I got this error :

> Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):   (no code object)
>   at line 0   File "/scratch/scripts/sails/checkscript.sh", line 2
>           python /scratch/scripts/sails/check_script1.py &
>                                                            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: what's wrong ? Well, to start with, you didn't properly format your bash code snippets, then you didn't post a proper MCVE.

Comment: I did. There is a new line after every python check_script*.py and check_script*.py &..... is there anything other than this i need to do?

Comment: Use python threading for concurrent running of your scripts

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

Comment: Looks like your system is trying to pass your shell script to python instead of passing it to the shell. The errors are Python errors, but they reference lines in the shell script.  Oh and yes, this has actually nothing to do with Python itself - it's a WLST issue.

Comment: FWIW: it looks like WLST expects Python scripts indeed, not shell scripts, cf https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/using_WLST.html :  "The WLST scripting environment is based on the Java scripting interpreter, Jython" (nb: never used WLST, this was in the very first link when googling "WLST")